# "When the internet first got kicking"?

Tags: vocabulary

> When the internet first got *kicking*, some scholars of democracy and civil society thought that online discussions could create what they called a "conversational democracy”: an ongoing town hall without bricks and mortar.

How to understand "kicking" in the context above? I learned from OED that

> **kicking**
>    adjective
>   (informal) full of life and excitement: The club was really kicking last night.

Does it have the same meaning here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its use here is more along the lines of this entry from *NOAD*:

> **alive and kicking** *informal* prevalent and very active : *bigotry is still alive and kicking*.

which, via *[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=alive)*:

> "The allusion is to a child in the womb after quickening" [Farmer].

Your *OED* reference may have the same origin.

Comment: I'd never made the connection to a fetus; I'd always thought of "alive and kicking" as having a connotation of (still!) alive.  That old Simple Minds song makes a bit more sense, then: "Stay until your love is / Alive and kicking..."

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that would be the proper meaning; with the slight adjustment to mean "had widespread activity" in this particular case.